# React setState inside useEffect wont work first call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I onpress method triggered the pressed useEffect api using promise in useEffect and according to incoming data set myDataStt and assign data to getData function I want to take action accordingly but I logged to getData func. triggered useEffect myDataStt wont change, press the buton second time this time succes myDataStt is change but first time press the button wont work (use effect triggered and value is correct) I dont understand why, thanks for comments

```
const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
const [myDataStt, setMyData] = useState(announcements);

useEffect(() => {
CallApi.then(
    values => {
        setMyData(values);
        const data = getData();
    }),
}, [pressed]);

const getData = () => {
    return myDataStt.dataFirst || [];
};

<Button
    onPress={() => {
        setPressed(true);
}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `useEffect` in manner. Have your button actually perform the API call. If you want the API to load data on the component mount, then have it called in `useEffect` and on click. There is no need for a pressed state. You can assign your function to a callback, so it doesn't trigger an infinite loop.

```
const getData = useCallback(async () => {
  const values = await CallApi();
  setMyData(values);
}, [setMyData]);

useEffect(()=> {
  getData();
}, [getData])

<Button onClick={() => getData()}>Refresh API</Button>
```

Comment: No I don't want this, I shortened my code to be an example I use elsewhere getData function and like initializing

Answer (score 0):

Look if this complete component works for you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const CallAPI = () => {
  //do your request/fetch
};

export const Component = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialCall = async () => {
      const values = await CallAPI();
      setData(values);
    };
    initialCall();
    return () => {
      //clean your fetch
    };
  }, []);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const values = await CallAPI();
    setData(values);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      {data.map(item => {
        return <div>{item}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

2 remarks, you dont need 2 states for call your api, try to use onClick in buttons.